# App-Error_handling Service going in loop when exception occurred in angular Application

Tags: error-handling, browser, crash

I have created an app-error-handle service for my whole application so that it will handle exception errors ... but when an exception occurs in my code this service goes into a loop and my browser crashes how to fix it.

my code for handling error:

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { RoutingService } from './routing.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppErrorHandlerService extends ErrorHandler {
  /**
   * List of error strings to be ignored and not logged.
   * Add more error strings to this list if needed.
   */
  private readonly ignoredErrorStrings: string[] = [
    'Cannot activate an already activated outlet',
    'cordova_not_available'
  ];

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    super();
  }

  /**
   * Handles and logs errors that occur in the application.
   * @param error The error object to be handled.
   */
  override handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {
    const http = this.injector.get(HttpService);
    const router = this.injector.get(RoutingService);

    console.error('AppErrorHandler', error);

    const errorMessage = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();

    // Determine if the error should be logged based on ignored error strings.
    const shouldLogError = this.ignoredErrorStrings.every((excErrorString) => {
      return errorMessage.indexOf(excErrorString) < 0;
    });

    // If the error should be logged, send a POST request to log the error.
    if (shouldLogError) {
      http.post(
        'error/log',
        {
          data: {
            error: errorMessage,
            route: router.getActive()
          }
        },
        (res) => {}
      );
    }

    super.handleError(error);
  }
}
```

i want error should handle properly and browser should not get crashed.

Comment: Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1502.9
@angular-devkit/build-angular   15.2.9
@angular-devkit/core            15.2.9
@angular-devkit/schematics      15.2.9
@schematics/angular             15.2.9
rxjs                            7.5.7
typescript                      4.8.4